# How to change origin of html5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I couldn't find answers for html5 canvas. Can I change the coordinates of the origin, so that my grafics will move altogether to the right for 15px (just an example). Given the following html and css?

```
<canvas id="g" width="auto" height="auto">Your browser doesnt support canvas tag</canvas>
```

css:

```
canvas, section {
    display: block;
}    

#g {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Comment: is redrawing the entire context an option? or do you just want to move the canvas element with css?

Comment: @arahaya redrawing would be awesome!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [translate transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations#Translating). Depending on what else you're doing with the context, you may also need to call [`save()` and `restore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations).

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(15, 0);
// ... do stuff with the transformed origin
ctx.restore();
// ... do stuff with the canvas restored to its original state (if necessary)
```

Comment: Note that if needed, you can reset the origin by calling `resetTransform()` instead of trying to `translate` back through all your changes. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/resetTransform) for details.